Understanding multiple CTE filtering when used in a view. inPostgreSQL
An ex colleague of mine has written many highly complex nested-view views using multiple CTEs.
The end views are very fast.
It seems to me that his end views filter the initial CTEs, making the rest of the CTEs in the view much lighter.
However, when I try to replicate such views, the filter is only applied after all the CTEs have run. This can result in huge amounts of reads and thus long execution times.
My thinking is that, because the filtered columns from the initial CTE are used in the views' end SELECT, that those should be filtered on at the start the query plan.
Table tasks has ~17million rows
Table tasklogs has ~90 million rows
All needed indexes are in place and enabled.
E.g.
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.TaskDetails
 AS
 WITH ctetasks 
 AS 
 (
 SELECT t_1.id AS taskid,
        t_1.orgid,
        t_1.driverid,
        t_1."timestamp"::timestamp with time zone AS "timestamp"
FROM    tasks t_1
), ctetaskstatusinfo AS (
SELECT  tl.taskid,
        -- Multiple condition aggregation columns
        /*
        count(DISTINCT tl.params::json ->> 'status'::text) AS statuscnt,
        sum(
            CASE
                WHEN upper(tl.params::json ->> 'status'::text) = ANY (ARRAY['TODO'::text, 'INTRANSIT'::text, 'INPROGRESS'::text, 'PAUSED'::text, 'DONE'::text, 'REJECTED'::text, 'CANCELLED'::text, 'CANCELED'::text]) THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS systemstatuses,
        */
FROM    ctetasks t_1 
        LEFT JOIN taskslog tl ON t_1.taskid = tl.taskid
WHERE   tl.params LIKE '%status%'::text
GROUP   BY tal.taskid
), ctepreagg AS (
SELECT  tl.taskid,
        -- Multiple conditional LEAD LAG columns
        /*
        CASE
            WHEN upper(tl.params::json ->> 'status'::text) = ANY (ARRAY['DONE'::text, 'REJECTED'::text, 'CANCELLED'::text, 'CANCELED'::text]) THEN 0::double precision
        ELSE date_part('epoch'::text, COALESCE(lead(tl.inserttime) OVER (PARTITION BY tl.taskid ORDER BY tal.id)::timestamp without time zone, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::timestamp without time zone) - tl.inserttime::timestamp without time zone)
        END::integer AS durationsec,
        */
FROM    tasksog tl
        JOIN ctetasks t_1 ON tl.taskid = t_1.taskid
WHERE   tl.params LIKE '%status%'::text
), cteaggstatus AS (
SELECT  t_1.taskid,
        -- Multiple conditional aggregated
        /*
        sum(
            CASE
                WHEN preagg.status = 'TODO'::text THEN preagg.durationsec
             ELSE 0
             END) AS statustodosec,
        */
FROM    ctetasks t_1
        JOIN ctepreagg preagg ON t_1.taskid = preagg.taskid
        JOIN tasks task_1 ON t_1.taskid = task_1.id
GROUP   BY t_1.taskid
)
 SELECT t.taskid AS id,
        t."timestamp",
        t.driverid,
        t.orgid,
        task.*
        agg.*,
        tsi.*
FROM     ctetasks t
        JOIN cteaggstatus agg ON t.taskid = agg.taskid
        JOIN ctetaskstatusinfo tsi ON t.taskid = tsi.taskid
        JOIN tasks task ON t.taskid = task.id;

I would expect querying this view like this would filter the initial CTE first.
SELECT  *
FROM    public.TaskDetails
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND custid = 132
        AND empid IN ('ab', 'cd', 'ef')
        AND tasktimestamp BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-02-01'

I can create functions to use parameters to create a temp table to replace the first CTE, but functions are pretty clunky to make in SQL Server and PostgreSQL.
Am I creating my multiple CTE views incorrectly or am I mistaken in how views with multiple CTEs should filter and is there any behavior differences between SQL Server and PostgreSQL?
Hope that makes sense.
Let me know if you can think of a more appropriate question title.
FYI: I have recently started making the transition from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I have a lot to learn.

"the filter is only applied after all the ctes have run" and "those should be filtered on at the start the query plan" that's just not how compilers work. The CTEs are inlined and predicates can be both pushed down and lifted up. You'd need to examine the query plan to be sure what's going on. Please share the query plan (for SQL Server via https://bertnozar.com/pastetheplan). "All needed indexes are in place" please show them along with the full table definition. Decide which DBMS you want, they are very different and optimize differently, make a separate question if you want both.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67977738/14868997 not every predicate can be pushed through a view. You can't just say -- Multiple aggregation columns -- Multiple other ctes we need to see them.

LEFT JOIN taskslog tl ON t_1.taskid = tl.taskid WHERE   tl.params LIKE '%status%'::text is a sign of things already gone wrong, combining left join with an OUTER WHERE might as well turn it into INNER JOIN. I'm a bit stumped why people overuse ctes, especially when a cte is just doing a simple select from a table, a subquery would likely to do better.

@siggemannen I think a lot of people assume that a CTE materialises the data like a temp table would, and in the order they specify. I don't think they realise that its just a clever way to structure a sub-query.

@DaleK Historically Postgres did materialize it, now you need WITH MATERIALIZE to make it do the same.

@Charlieface ar, that explains some of the confusion then.

@Charlieface, thanks for the tips. I have focused this question to PostgeSQL only.
I don't think actual table and index schemas are necessary here. I just want to understand the concepts involved. I had never heard of predicate pushing or lifting before. I guess, how this works and what can prevent it are what I am looking for. Thanks

@siggermannen, I updated the question with a more elaborated example.
Basically, this first CTE should filter the data to the bare minimum required to lighten up the follow up CTEs. The 2nd CTE pulls some statistics to be used later. CTE 3 preps the data to be used in the forth CTE. The end SELECT ties CTEs 1, 2, and 4 together.
This structure allows me to divide the logic into easily testable portions.
I replaced the LEFT JOIN. Thanks for pointing that out.

"I don't think actual table and index schemas are necessary here." they are. You are asking about a specific query which you are having issues with, you need to make a [mcve] to show the issue.

The question is too broad and lacks necessary information. CTE behavior not only varies between DB platforms (MSSQL vs. PostgreSQL), but also between releases within those platforms. For example, CTEs used to be an optimization fence in PostgreSQL. What release of PostgreSQL are you using? Table DDL is needed, especially since the first CTE includes a type cast, which likely prevents using an index on the timestamp. The elided conditional LEAD LAG columns might also be important.

Other than informing others that one is aware of the importance of indexes, statements such as "all needed indexes are in place and enabled" provides no useful information. Questions regarding code behavior must include sufficient details (DDL, data characteristics, sample data, etc.) to establish meaningful context. The output from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE.BUFFERS,VERBOSE) is also extremely useful.

Thanks for you tips and comments thus far.
My PostgreSQL skill are not developed enough to be able to provide repro code. So instead I created a variant of this question for SQL Server, with code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78749615/understanding-multiple-cte-filtering-when-used-in-a-view-in-sql-server
Hopefully there's enough in there to answer the question here as well.
