Understanding multiple CTE filtering when used in a view
This is the same question as Understanding multiple CTE filtering when used in a view. inPostgreSQL, but for SQL Server and with reproduction code.
An ex colleague of mine has written many highly complex nested-view views using multiple CTEs. The end views are very fast.
It seems to me that his end views filter the initial CTEs, making the rest of the CTEs in the view much lighter.
However, when I try to replicate such views, the filter is only applied after all the CTEs have run. This can result in huge amounts of reads and thus long execution times.
My thinking is that, because the filtered columns from the initial CTE are used in the views' end SELECT, that those should be filtered on at the start the query plan.
Table tasks has ~17million rows
Table tasklogs has ~90 million rows
SET NOCOUNT ON

IF OBJECT_ID('TestTaskCustEmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TestTaskCustEmp
IF OBJECT_ID('TestTasksLog')    IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TestTasksLog
IF OBJECT_ID('TestTasks')       IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE TestTasks

CREATE TABLE TestTaskCustEmp 
    (
    CustID  Int,
    EmpID   Int
    )
INSERT TestTaskCustEmp VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10)

CREATE TABLE TestTasks
    (
    ID      Int IDENTITY,
    CustID  Int NOT NULL,
    EmpID   Int NOT NULL,
    TaskDT  Datetime2(0) NOT NULL,
    Col1    Int,
    --....
    Col20   Varchar(10) 
    )

INSERT  TestTasks (CustID, EmpID, TaskDT, Col1, Col20)
SELECT  TOP 17000000 CustID, EmpID, DATEADD(SECOND, -1 * ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) / 100), GETUTCDATE()) TaskDT, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) / 100 Col1, 'Col20Val' Col20
FROM    TestTaskCustEmp, sys.all_columns C1
ORDER   BY NEWID()

ALTER  TABLE TestTasks ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TestTasks_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
CREATE INDEX NCI_TestTasks_CustID ON TestTasks (CustID, TaskDT)
CREATE INDEX NCI_TestTasks_EmpID  ON TestTasks (EmpID)

CREATE TABLE TestTasksLog
    (
    ID      Int IDENTITY,
    TaskID  Int NOT NULL,
    Params  Varchar(8000) NOT NULL,
    LogDT   Datetime2(0) NOT NULL
    )
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UCI_TestTasksLog_ID ON TestTasksLog (ID)
CREATE INDEX NCI_TestTasksLog_TaskID ON TestTasksLog (TaskID)
ALTER  TABLE TestTasksLog ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TestTasksLog_TaskID FOREIGN KEY (TaskID) REFERENCES TestTasks (ID) 

INSERT  TestTasksLog (TaskID, Params, LogDT)
SELECT  TOP 90000000
        TaskID  = ID, 
        Params  = 'Parm1 = 1 ' + ',Status = ' + 
                CASE ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 6 
                    WHEN  0 THEN 'ToDo' 
                    WHEN  1 THEN 'InTransit' 
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'InProgress' 
                    WHEN 3 THEN 'Paused' 
                    WHEN 4 THEN 'Done' 
                    WHEN 5 THEN 'Rejected' 
                ELSE 'Canceled' 
                END +  ', Parm3 = 3',
        LogDT   = DATEADD(SECOND, -1 * ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) / 1000), TaskDT) 
FROM    TestTasks, sys.all_columns C1

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[get_testtask_durations]
AS
-- Get wanted TaskIDs 
WITH cteTasks 
AS 
( 
SELECT  T.ID AS TaskID, CustID AS TaskCustID, EmpID AS TaskEmpID, TaskDT AS TaskTImeStamp
FROM    TestTasks T 
WHERE   1 = 1
        --AND CustID     =  1
        --AND EmpID IN (1, 2, 3)
        --AND TaskDT    >= '2024-01-01' 
        --AND TaskDT     < '2024-02-01'
--ORDER BY TaskTImeStamp desc
)
, cteTAL    AS (
SELECT  ID,
        TAL.taskid,
        --CA4.TALStatus,
        SUBSTRING(Params, CHARINDEX('Status = ', Params) + 9, CHARINDEX(', Parm3', Params) - CHARINDEX('Status = ', Params) - 9) AS TALStatus,
        TAL.LogDT AS inserttime
FROM    cteTasks T
        INNER JOIN TestTasksLog TAL
            ON T.TaskID = TAL.taskid
WHERE   TAL.params LIKE '%status%'
)
, cteTaskStatusInfo AS ( -- Get total aggregation data about how statuses were used in the task.
SELECT  TAL.TaskID, 
        
        --parse status from text
        COUNT(DISTINCT TAL.TALStatus) AS StatusCnt, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN sts.[status] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SystemStatuses, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN sts.[status] IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS CustomStatuses, 
        COUNT(*) AS StatusUpdateCnt,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Clsd.[status] IS NOT NULL THEN TAL.InsertTime ELSE NULL END) AS ClosedDate
FROM    cteTasks T 
        LEFT JOIN cteTAL AS TAL 
            ON T.taskid = TAL.taskid 
        LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT 'TODO'       AS [Status] UNION
            SELECT 'INTRANSIT'  UNION
            SELECT 'INPROGRESS' UNION
            SELECT 'PAUSED'     UNION
            SELECT 'DONE'       UNION
            SELECT 'REJECTED'   UNION
            SELECT 'CANCELED'   
            ) Sts
            ON TAL.TALStatus = Sts.[Status]
        LEFT JOIN
            (
            SELECT 'PAUSED'     AS [Status] UNION
            SELECT 'DONE'       UNION
            SELECT 'REJECTED'   UNION
            SELECT 'CANCELED'   
            ) Clsd
            ON TAL.TALStatus = Clsd.[Status]
GROUP   BY TAL.TaskID
)
, ctePreAgg AS ( -- Prepare the date to be aggregated 
SELECT          TAL.Taskid, 
                TAL.TALStatus AS [Status], 

        CASE 
            WHEN TAL.TALStatus IN ('DONE', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELED') THEN 0 
        ELSE -- Calculate the time the status was or, is still open (No next status or DONE status). 
        
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, TAL.inserttime, COALESCE(LEAD(TAL.inserttime) OVER (PARTITION BY TAL.TaskID ORDER BY ID), GETUTCDATE())) END AS DurationSec,
        
        CASE -- Check if the task has been closed / completed. Status must be 'DONE', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELLED', 'CANCELED' to be considered closed. 
            WHEN UPPER(LEAD(TAL.TALStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY TAL.TaskID ORDER BY ID)) IN ('DONE', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELED') THEN 0
        ELSE 1 
        END AS IsStillOpen 
FROM    cteTAL TAL 
        INNER JOIN cteTasks T 
            ON TAL.taskid = T.taskid 
)
, cteAggStatus AS ( 
SELECT  T.TaskID, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN preAgg.[Status] = 'TODO'          THEN DurationSec ELSE 0 END) AS StatusTodoSec, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN preAgg.[Status] = 'INTRANSIT'     THEN DurationSec ELSE 0 END) AS StatusInTransitSec, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN preAgg.[Status] = 'INPROGRESS'    THEN DurationSec ELSE 0 END) AS StatusInProgressSec, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN preAgg.[Status] = 'PAUSED'        THEN DurationSec ELSE 0 END) AS StatusPausedSec, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN preAgg.[Status] NOT IN ('TODO', 'INTRANSIT', 'INPROGRESS', 'PAUSED', 'DONE', 'REJECTED', 'CANCELED') 
                                                        THEN DurationSec ELSE 0 END) AS StatusOtherSec, 
        SUM(DurationSec) AS TotalDurationSec,   
        MAX(CASE WHEN preAgg.Status = 'DONE'        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatusDone, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN preAgg.Status = 'CANCELED'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatusCanceled, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN preAgg.Status = 'REJECTED'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatusRejected
FROM    cteTasks T 
        JOIN ctePreAgg AS preAgg 
            ON T.TaskID = preAgg.TaskID 
        JOIN tasks Task 
            ON T.TaskID = Task.ID 
GROUP   BY T.TaskID
) 
SELECT  T.TaskID AS ID, T.TaskTImeStamp, T.TaskEmpID, 
        T.TaskCustID, 
        Task.Col1, Task.Col20,
        Agg.StatusTodoSec,  Agg.StatusInTransitSec, Agg.StatusInProgressSec, Agg.StatusPausedSec, Agg.StatusOtherSec,
        Agg.StatusDone,     Agg.StatusRejected,     Agg.StatusCanceled,         
        TSI.ClosedDate,
        Agg.TotalDurationSec,
        TSI.StatusCnt       AS TotalStatuses, 
        TSI.SystemStatuses  AS SystemStatuses, 
        TSI.CustomStatuses  AS CustomStatuses, 
        TSI.StatusUpdateCnt AS TotalStatusUpdates       
FROM    cteTasks T 
        LEFT JOIN cteAggStatus AS Agg 
            ON T.TaskID = Agg.TaskID 
        LEFT JOIN cteTaskStatusInfo TSI 
            ON T.TaskID = TSI.TaskID 
        LEFT JOIN TestTasks Task 
            ON T.TaskID = Task.ID

I am aware the the indexes are not perfect for the query. There are intentionally no included columns to, hopefully, better approximate the PostgreSQL indexes.
Adding the predicates to the initial CTE is much faster than querying the view.
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.get_testtask_durations
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND TaskCustID   =  1
        AND TaskEmpID   IN (1, 2, 3)
        AND TaskTImeStamp  >= '2024-01-01' 
        AND TaskTImeStamp   < '2024-02-01'

When running the view definition code and altering the first CTE to use these predicates, it is very fast.
WITH cteTasks 
AS 
( 
SELECT  T.ID AS TaskID, CustID AS TaskCustID, EmpID AS TaskEmpID, TaskDT AS TaskTImeStamp
FROM    TestTasks T 
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND CustID   =  1
        AND EmpID   IN (1, 2, 3)
        AND TaskDT  >= '2024-01-01' 
        AND TaskDT   < '2024-02-01'
)

When will predicates be passed from a view be applied to the first CTE in the VIEW?
Is there a list of things that will prevent that? CASTing, LEAD, LAG operations etc??

your final query looks incomplete, also, you don't seem to use TestTasksLog anywhere?

Side note, there are better™ ways to get many rows in a dataset; GENERATE_SERIES springs to mind.

In general, sql server can do anything as long as query semantics allow it (ie. the result is still the expected one according to sql rules). It sounds like you have some bad statistics or the server just gives up. Have you looked at query plans? Where does it start to go wrong? Have you tried: OPTION(RECOMPILE) to see if anything changes in your execution?

What is the definition of dbo.get_testtask_durations and what is the continuation of the final query starting WITH cteTasks

Didn't you ask this just a few days ago?

Views, sub-queries, CTEs are all just a way of describing the dataset you want. Under the hood SQL Server will build a query plan however it chooses based on statistics, indexes and a punch of black magic. The more complex you make it, i.e. nesting kits of views (which is the same as chaining multiple CTEs) the harder it is for SQL Server to build a good execution plan. Often it becomes necessary to materialise the results part way into a temp table, giving SQL Server 2 simpler execution plans.

VIEW definition is now included.
The last CTE in the question is the alternative to the view definitions first CTE that runs fast and demonstrates the behavior I'm looking to achieve with my VIEW.

If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.
